# Как создать обертку двух разных классов с одинаковыми полями?

Tags: java, ооп, swing

Пишу окно, в котором постоянно должны двигаться круги\квадраты. Показываются только круги\квадраты, но в этом время другие фигуры двигаются.

(вот гит с исходником: https://github.com/Kaper156/MovingFigures)

Я решил дополнить классы стандартных фигур (MovingCircle, MovingSquare) и реализовать в них направление и расчет следующей точки (а также изменение направления при столкновении).

Проблема в следующем: мне пришлось написать два практически идентичных класса **(MovingCircle, MovingSquare)**, которые дополняют Ellipse2d.Double и Rectangle2d.Double соответственно. 
**Как сделать общий для этих двух классов "передвигатель"?** 
Ведь нужные мне координаты и размеры доступны только в последней реализации.

```
public class MovingSquare extends Rectangle2D.Double implements MovingFigure {
    private float angle;
    public Color color;

    MovingSquare() {
        Random r = new Random();
        this.width = this.height = r.nextInt(20) + 5;
        this.angle = r.nextFloat() * 360;
        this.x = width * 3 + r.nextDouble() * (CANVAS_W - width * 6);
        this.y = height * 3 + r.nextDouble() * (CANVAS_H - height * 6);
        this.color = new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat());
    }

    public void MoveSelf() {

        x = x + Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * SPEED;
        y = y + Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * SPEED;

        if (x <= this.width || x >= CANVAS_W - width * 2) {
            angle = 180 - angle;
        }

        if (y <= this.height || y >= CANVAS_H - height * 2) {
            angle = 360 - angle;
        }

    }
}

public class MovingCircle extends Ellipse2D.Double implements MovingFigure {

    private float angle;
    public Color color;

    MovingCircle() {
        Random r = new Random();
        this.width = this.height = r.nextInt(20) + 5;
        this.angle = r.nextFloat() * 360;
        this.x = width * 3 + r.nextDouble() * (CANVAS_W - width * 6);
        this.y = height * 3 + r.nextDouble() * (CANVAS_H - height * 6);
        this.color = new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat());
    }

    public void MoveSelf() {

        x = x + Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * SPEED;
        y = y + Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * SPEED;

        //TODO radius
        if (x <= this.width || x >= CANVAS_W - width * 2) {
            angle = 180 - angle;
        }

        if (y <= this.height || y >= CANVAS_H - height * 2) {
            angle = 360 - angle;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Правильно ли будет создать два соответствующих класса (ExtCircle, ExtSquare), которые будут иметь ссылку на MovingFigure (в нем будет повторяющийся код)?

Comment: А кто должен знать, как фигуре двигаться?

Comment: Фигуры двигаются одинаково (не стал разбирать отдельно соприкосновение радиуса круга и стенки квадрата). Перемещения просчитываются для каждой фигуры при перерисовке. Панель владеет двумя списками этих фигур

Answer (score 1):

Я бы взглянул в торону генериков бы, и определил базовый класс, с указанием фигуры в виде параметра генерика.

Comment: Не могу обратиться к полям дженерика, может есть еще варианты?

Comment: А почему нет возможности?